# Attributes 'qRegisterResourceData' and 'qUnregisterResourceData' in QT6 library

Tags: python, qt, qt5, qtcore, qt6

I am trying to compile a Python application written for Python2 under MacOs (Monterey) with M1 (ooph!).

1. Instead of Python 2 I am using Python 3 (3.8.9)
2. Instead of QT5 I have to use QT6 (QT5 refuses to install with different pip versions and different versions of QT5)

Having substituted lines like
`from PyQt5 import QtCore`
to
`from PyQt6 import QtCore`, I finally stuck with the following error trying start the application:

```
  File "pyjtt_res_rc.py", line 14407, in qInitResources
    QtCore.qRegisterResourceData(0x01, qt_resource_struct, qt_resource_name, qt_resource_data)
AttributeError: module 'PyQt6.QtCore' has no attribute 'qRegisterResourceData'
```

according to the comment, this file is a `# Resource object code` and contains basically

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore

qt_resource_data = b"\
\x00\x00\x15\x46\
....
"

def qInitResources():
    QtCore.qRegisterResourceData(0x01, qt_resource_struct, qt_resource_name, qt_resource_data)

def qCleanupResources():
    QtCore.qUnregisterResourceData(0x01, qt_resource_struct, qt_resource_name, qt_resource_data)

qInitResources()
```

I believe something has been changed in QT6 and now I have to use other attributes or these attributes are now located in other module.

Any ideas what to do?

Comment: These functions were missing in earlier versions of pyqt6, but were added in version 6.3.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resources control module has been removed from QT6. Deprecate these two functions from the code and also remove additional call of qInitResources(). It and all will work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).